# Iterate nested array of objects, find id and update object matching the id

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have below input as follows. Its an array of objects and each object has states which is also a array of objects. i want to append `details` inside the states object when the state id matches with the `id` mentioned below. i.e. `82175746`

```
const input = 
[
    {
        "country": { "id": 87745195, "action": "Analyze" },
        "states": [
            { "id": 83589582, "action": "Verify" },
            { "id": 87335656, "action": "Analyze" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": { "id": 83861166, "action": "Verify" },
        "states": [
            { "id": 82175746, "action": "Closed" },
            { "id": 78745158, "action": "Closed" }
        ]
    }
]


const details = { "totalOpenRadars": 1, "totalClosedRadars": 1 }

const id = 82175746
```

And this is the result i am trying to achieve. Please note that id of 82175746 is compared with all the state ids. once a match is found, details mentioned above is appended as shown below to the matched object.

```
const result = 
[
    {
        "country": { "id": 87745195, "action": "Analyze" },
        "states": [
            { "id": 83589582, "action": "Verify" },
            { "id": 87335656, "action": "Analyze" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": { "id": 83861166, "action": "Verify" },
        "states": [
            { "id": 82175746, "action": "Closed", "details": { "totalOpenRadars": 1, "totalClosedRadars": 1 } },
            { "id": 78745158, "action": "Closed" }
        ]
    }
]
```

In order to achieve this, I tried this way but I am not able to get the result properly.
Can someone please let me know where I went wrong

```
const result  = input.forEach((element) => {
    element.states.forEach((state) => {
        if(state.id === id) {
            state.details = details
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.forEach` always returns `undefined`, so `result` will always be `undefined`. If you look at `input` after your operation, it does contain your details as you specified.

Alternatively, you could spread `input` into a new array called `result` and perform your loop on `result` instead if you intend to keep `input` the same.

```js
const input = 
[
    {
        "country": { "id": 87745195, "action": "Analyze" },
        "states": [
            { "id": 83589582, "action": "Verify" },
            { "id": 87335656, "action": "Analyze" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": { "id": 83861166, "action": "Verify" },
        "states": [
            { "id": 82175746, "action": "Closed" },
            { "id": 78745158, "action": "Closed" }
        ]
    }
]


const details = { "totalOpenRadars": 1, "totalClosedRadars": 1 }

const id = 82175746

input.forEach((element) => {
    element.states.forEach((state) => {
        if(state.id === id) {
            state.details = details
        }

    });
});
console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const input = [{"country": { "id": 87745195, "action": "Analyze" },"states": [{ "id": 83589582, "action": "Verify" },{ "id": 87335656, "action": "Analyze" }]},{"country": { "id": 83861166, "action": "Verify" },"states": [{ "id": 82175746, "action": "Closed" },{ "id": 78745158, "action": "Closed" }]}]
const details = { "totalOpenRadars": 1, "totalClosedRadars": 1 }
const id = 82175746

const result = input.map(item => item.states.map(state => ({
  ...state,
  ...(state.id === id ? { details } : {})
})))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be do it

```js
const appendDetails = (data, id, details) => 
  data.map(d => {
    return {
      ...d,
      states: d.states.map(s => {
        if(s.id !== id){
          return s
        }
        return {
          ...s,
          details
        }
      })
    } 
  })

const input = 
[
    {
        "country": { "id": 87745195, "action": "Analyze" },
        "states": [
            { "id": 83589582, "action": "Verify" },
            { "id": 87335656, "action": "Analyze" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": { "id": 83861166, "action": "Verify" },
        "states": [
            { "id": 82175746, "action": "Closed" },
            { "id": 78745158, "action": "Closed" }
        ]
    }
]


const details = { "totalOpenRadars": 1, "totalClosedRadars": 1 }

const id = 82175746

console.log(appendDetails(input, id, details))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reusable approaches not only key or value, each possible element with neat and clean way.

you can change array, object key where look into, key where want to match with value, and new key and new value.

```js
const students = [
    {
      "name": "Amoos",
      "skills": [
        { id: 11, name: "html" },
        { id: 12, name: "css" }
      ],
      "sports": [
        {id: 31, name: "football"},
        {id: 32, name: "circket"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Rifat",
      "skills": [
        { id: 21, name: "reactjs" },
        { id: 22, name: "nextjs" }
      ],
      "sports": [
        {id: 41, name: "baseball"},
        {id: 42, name: "volleyball"},
      ]
    },
]

 

const addNewValueByKeyInArray = (arrayData, where, key, value, newKey, newValue ) => {
   return arrayData.map(( d ) => d[where].map((w) => (w[key] === value) ? {
            ...w, [newKey]: newValue
        } : {...w}
    ))
}

// EXAMPL #1
console.log(addNewValueByKeyInArray(students, 'sports', 'id', 42, 'details', { 'region': 'worldwide', 'first_played': '1895' }));

// EXAMPL #2
console.log(addNewValueByKeyInArray(students, 'skills', 'id', 22, 'details', { 'author': 'Guillermo Rauch', 'first_version': '2016' }));
```